# How to refresh data in shared Excel 2010 workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a Excel 2010 workbook that is shared by other users who periodically update various cells.  Is there a shortcut key, like F5 with most web browsers, that updates the document with any changes that have been made since I opened the workbook?

The following do not work:

- F5
- F9
- SHFT + F9
- CTRL + ALT + F9
- CTRL + ALT + SHFT F9

Answer (score 6):

Hitting Save works, as long as you are careful not to save anything you didn't want.

It's definitely odd that f5 doesn't refresh in Excel.

Comment: I would love to have a way to do it not involving saving, honestly.

Answer (score 5):

Create a macro

```
Sub Makro1()
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

Assing keyboard shortcut to the macro

Answer (score 1):

try <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>

or go to `data - connections - refresh all - refresh all`

Comment: ctrl+alt+f5 does not work

Comment: data > connections has no connections and Refresh is greyed out

Comment: That refreshes data sources, not the document itself.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>A</kbd> in sequence will refresh the data.

Answer (score -1):

Use Review, Track Changes, check Track changes while editing, and select the options you want.

Comment: The OP was asking how to refresh data. I don't remember using a shared spreadsheet that also had data to refresh, but I suppose you could unshare, refresh, then re-share(?).